# Python: dict and sorting in alphabetical

Tags: python, sorting, csv, dictionary

I require to write a program which accept input year from user and read information from CSV file then export result on the screen. The csv source file has format: `year, name, count, gender` and export result are boy only with format `Name     Count` in alphabetical order.

Input file:

```
2010,Ruby,440,Female

2010,Cooper,493,Male
```

Output:

```
Please enter the year: 2010
Popular boy names in year 2010 are:
     Aidan  112
```

I have error when run program:

```
Please enter the year: 2014
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\SIT111\A1\printBoynameTPL.py", line 26, in <module>
        year, name, count, gender = row
    ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

This is my code:

```
'''
This program accepts a year as input from a user and print boys' information of the year. The output should be  sorted by name in alphabetical order.


Steps:
1. Receive a year from a user

2. Read CSV files: 
Format: year, name, count, gender

3. Display popular boy names  on the screen:
Format:    Name     Count

'''

import csv

inputYear = raw_input('Please enter the year: ')
inFile = open('output/babyQldAll.csv', 'rU')
cvsFile = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')

dict = {}

for row in  cvsFile:
    year, name, count, gender = row  

    if (year == inputYear) and (gender == 'Boy'):
        dict[name] =  count

print('Popular boy names in year %s are:' % inputYear)

# +++++ You code here ++++
# According to informaiton in 'dict',  print (name, count) sorted by 'name' in alphabetical order         
sortedName = shorted(dict.keys())
for name in sortedName:
    print(name, dict[name])
print("Print boy names... ")    


inFile.close()
```

I edited a bit:

```
for row in  cvsFile:
        if row:
            year, name, count, gender = row  

            if (year == inputYear) and (gender == 'Male'):
                dict[name] =  count  
print('Popular boy names in year %s are:' % inputYear)
# +++++ You code here ++++
# According to informaiton in 'dict',  print (name, count) sorted by 'name' in alphabetical order         
sortedName = sorted(dict.keys())
for name in sortedName:
        print(name,dict[name])
print("Print boy names... ")
```

did i do sth wrong? indents or sth?

result:

```
>>> 
Please enter the year: 2013
Popular boy names in year 2013 are:
Print boy names... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having empty lines in your csv file, which is causing empty `row` to come you iterate the csv file. You can simply check if `row` is empty or not, before doing rest of the logic. Example -

```
for row in  cvsFile:
    if row:
        year, name, count, gender = row  

        if (year == inputYear) and (gender == 'Boy'):
            dict[name] =  count
```

Also, you should not use `dict` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in function `dict()` .

Also, you have another typo in your program -

```
sortedName = shorted(dict.keys())
```

I am guessing you intended to use `sorted()` .

Comment: oh damn! it's my spelling mistake. Now it's work fine but no result export to the screen. 

    Please enter the year: 2013
    Popular boy names in year 2013 are:
    Print boy names...

Comment: I notice that in the actual csv you have `Male` / `Female` . But for checking you are using `Boy` , can that be the issue?

Comment: i changed to 'male' but still the same problem, nothing exported

Comment: `capital M` in male? try printing each element before comparing, if you are not getting any result, it means the condition is not getting satisfied for an row.

Comment: yes, 'Male' but it's not work.
but in my csv file, in each element have a blank line, etc: 2010,Chloe,398,Female one line blank and 
2010,Lachlan,430,Male
is it affect this code?

Comment: no it should not, did you print `year` and `gender` before the `if` condition , what did it print?

Comment: i edited in my questions, now it work but seems like it's stuck in a infinitive loop and not in alphabetical order.

Comment: Can you also update the code which is causing the infinite loop?

Comment: Your indentation for `sortednames()` , etc seem to be inside the previous for loop, you should make it outside.

Comment: Try printing `year` and `gender` before the `if` condtion and let me know what you get.

Comment: By the way you are running this as a script right? If not, atleast you are openning the file again and again?

Comment: i put the line  [   if (year == inputYear) and (gender == 'Male'): ] in the same allign with [for row in cvsFile: ] but it is the same trouble

Comment: no don't put like that. Like I said please check the prints and let me know how you are running the program?

Comment: you mean put a line `print(name, gender)`  before `if (year == inputYear) and (gender == 'Male'):` ?

Comment: it export a list: `('Alex', 'Male')
('Lillian', 'Female')
('Jaxson', 'Male')
('Skye', 'Female')
('Jai', 'Male')
('Alexandra', 'Female')
('Tyson', 'Male')
('Madeline', 'Female')
('Nathan', 'Male')
('Lola', 'Female')
('Harley', 'Male')
('Gabriella', 'Female')
('John', 'Male')
Popular boy names in year 2013 are:
Print boy names... `

Comment: What does `print(dict)` after this line - `print('Popular boy names in year %s are:' % inputYear)` , give?

Comment: So most probably the year is the one causing the issue, are you seeing same empty result for `2010`?

Comment: because there is no data for 2013 ?

Comment: I check the csv source file, well, that's the problem, thanks!